# terraform : find out if AWS Service is supported in targeted region

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codepipeline

We are using codepipeline to deploy our application on to the AWS EC2 Nodes.

However codepipeline is not supported in all the AWS Regions and causing our terraform deployment to fail.

I would like to use userdatascript on AWS EC2 nodes, where AWS Regions lacking support of AWS Codepipeline.

Is there any way for me to detect/findout if codepipeline service supported/or not on targeted region through Terraform ?

AWS provides endpoint for the codepipeline in this documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/codepipeline.html

My logical/hypothetical solution here is below

1. Run the curl command via [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html)  or use [http get data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http) to hit the endpoints on targeted region , the endpoint follow the below pattern `https://codepipeline.<InsertTargetedRegion>.amazonaws.com`
2. From the result of the step 1, make logical decision. if endpoint is reachable, create AWS Codepipeline and downstream resources, if endpoint is not reachable, create EC2 LC with userdata script and drop the AWS Codepipeline.

The other solution ( which is little clumsy ) , I can think of is to make a terraform list for the regions which do not support codepipeline as service and make some logical decision based on that.

However this clumsy solution required human effort (checking/knowing if region support aws codepipeline and update terraform list ) and updating terraform configuration every now and then.

I am wondering, if there is any other way to know if targeted region supports codepipeline or not.

Thank You.

Comment: Why not hard-code the service availability into a constant or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a static file, but is it a scalable solution? How can you track if a new region adds. I think this link will help you.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-query-for-aws-regions-endpoints-and-more-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/

With AWS CLI you can query services availability with regions

Answer (score 0):

I think that having a static list of supported regions is simply the easiest and most direct way of knowing where the script can run. Then the logic is quite easy: if the current region is supported continue, if not error and stop. Any other logic will be cumbersome and unnecessary.

Comment: Agree ! However maintaining the list of supported regions is little cumbersome solution (As I have mentioned in my another solution idea ) as you will have to keep on updating it for the future.